# Error - Nuxtjs middleware Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

I'm fairly new to Nuxtjs and I am having some issues.

I am using Node v12.13.0 and Nuxt "^2.15.7". when

I then received the following error:

```
     ERROR  Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client                                          11:40:04      
      at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:485:11)
      at Storage.setCookie (server.js:2665:20)
      at Storage.setUniversal (server.js:2517:10)
      at Token._setToken (server.js:3384:26)
      at Token.reset (server.js:3349:10)
      at RefreshScheme.reset (server.js:4249:16)
      at Auth.reset (server.js:2867:31)
      at RefreshScheme.logout (server.js:3602:23)
      at Auth.logout (server.js:2846:47)
      at refreshToken (server.js:2351:153)
      at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
      at async Timeout._onTimeout (server.js:2351:844)
```

My code: My following code nuxt middleware refresh_token.js.

```
     function decodeToken (token) {
        const base64 =  JSON.parse(Buffer.from(token.split('.')[1], 'base64').toString('utf-8'))
        const exp = base64.exp
        const now = Date.now() / 1000
        let timeUntilRefresh = exp ? exp - now : false
        timeUntilRefresh -= (1 * 60)
        return timeUntilRefresh
    }
     
    async function refreshToken ($api, $auth, refresh_token) {
        try {
            if (refresh_token) {
                const response = await $api.post('api/private/user/refresh-token', {
                    refresh_token: refresh_token
                })
                $auth.setUserToken(response.data.token, response.data.refresh_token)
                return decodeToken($auth.strategy.refreshToken.get())    
            }
        } catch (err) {
            $auth.logout()
            throw new Error('Error while refreshing token')
        }
       
    }
     
    export default async function ({ app }) {
        const { $api, $auth } = app
        let refresh_token = $auth.strategy.refreshToken.get()
        let refreshInterval = 500
        if (refresh_token) {
            const timeUntilRefresh = decodeToken(refresh_token)
            refreshInterval = timeUntilRefresh
            if (timeUntilRefresh <= 300 && timeUntilRefresh >= 0) {
                await refreshToken($api, $auth, refresh_token)
                refreshInterval = 500
            }
            if (refreshInterval < 0) {
                refreshInterval = await refreshToken($api, $auth, refresh_token)
            }
            setInterval(async function () {
                refresh_token = $auth.strategy.refreshToken.get()
                await refreshToken($api, $auth, refresh_token)
            }, refreshInterval * 1000)
        }    
    }
```

May I know what is wrong with my code? Thank you so much